# I can't hear any audio

Tags: sound

Previously i had Ubuntu 16.04 and could hear sound, due to the problem in motherboard i had to change the board. After the board has been changed, i can't hear any audio. Some of the links i have tried to fix this issue, but could not get it working:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure
- https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-no-sound-issue-ubuntu/
- https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-nosound.html.en

Tried to fix by upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 but no luck, can anyone please help me bring back the sound ??

pavucontrol screenshot as follows:

[image: Configuration Tab]

[image: Output Devices]

Comment: The first link provided has details on necessary information required in order to get more help; why did you not provide that detail here? and did you try answers.launchpad.net? (if so why not provide a link here of what you posted as we can get details there of your hardware), otherwise what hardware is recognized by the kernel?  (`sudo lshw -C sound` is my usual goto but it's less useful than used in the two official guides you listed)

Comment: audio hardware recognized is: *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:30 memory:f7d10000-f7d13fff

Comment: Please don't put information in comments, edit your question and put it there (it's much easier to read, can be formatted and edited with greater ease etc).  It looks recognized, so I'd look in `pavucontrol` or pulse-audio-volume-control (configuration & output tabs specifically)

Comment: sorry for this, configuration and output devices screenshot added, please have a look